# Is it good practise to have select element's option value as id of records (HTML)?

Tags: html, angular, validation, angular-material

I am using angular 7 and material where I am using a select element for the dropdown purpose like -

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Select">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let listData of List; let m = index" (onSelectionChange)="onChanged($event,listData )" **[value]='listData ?.id'** >
    {{ listData.name }}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

and It will appear like

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Select">
   <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onChanged($event,listData )" **value='660-999-000-888-909'** >
    Test 1
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onChanged($event,listData )" **value='661-990-001-881-901'** >
    Test 1
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

so is it a data breach or can be processed? if wrong what should be best practice, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb anything you do not want your end user to know/extract you should not send them. So if the value is important in that it can pose a security concern or could be used maliciously then it should never have been sent to the browser to begin with. I have no idea what `660-999-000-888-909` means but if it is a personal identifying piece of information like a SSN or if I can use that as a password to gain entry into a system then the answer is "It is a security concern and do not proceed".

Answer (score 2):

original intent of combo box (or select box in html) is to present list of human readable options, where each one is associated with machine readable id, this is why we have `value` attribute and inner text to display

so, usage of id here is the right way of doing things

now, next problem - whether providing user with id is security problem, this is pretty much depend on how you generate these ids and whether they could expose sensitive information:

if they are random GUIDs, then it is a not a big deal (unless you're using old version, which can [expose mac address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843346/how-easy-is-it-for-a-guid-you-generate-to-identify-you))

if you're using pure incremental ids - then it could give attacker information about total number of users/orders/etc and thus for example reveal number or pre-orders for new game/device

but for majority of data - it does not matter whether user knows that some "status" field has id 5, so you can put them into html

note - we're speaking here about [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (IDs), don't use natural ids like passport numbers